# Add Calendar Option to Jasper Report

Tags: calendar, date, report, icons

I spun up a Jasper Reports server (**version 6.3**) and I'm migrating reports from our old server (**5.0.0**). Some of the reports in the old instance have options for **date ranges**. In the 5.0.0 instance users can can click a '**calendar icon**' and select month/year/day. In the new instance I spun up I only get a text box for entering dates.

How do I got about getting this **calendar icon** to appear on my form in the **6.3 instance**?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add the calendar icon by following the steps provided here: http://jasper-bi-suite.blogspot.in/2014/03/jasper-server-calendar-date-input.html

Since I had already added the input for the user to enter dates I had to delete and recreate them but once I did that the icon appeared.